# Matlab to Latex data exceed memory limit error

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab

Sometimes I feel its easier to use Matlab to draw figures, but I save them to data files and then plot them in Latex to have the same font styles, colors, etc. But I'm facing couple of problems like this one. I used a matlab code which available online to compare between different filters, I save the output as shown below

```matlab
n = 5;
f = 2e9;

[zb,pb,kb] = butter(n,2*pi*f,'s');
[bb,ab] = zp2tf(zb,pb,kb);
[hb,wb] = freqs(bb,ab,4096);
[z1,p1,k1] = cheby1(n,3,2*pi*f,'s');

[b2,a2] = zp2tf(z2,p2,k2);
[h2,w2] = freqs(b2,a2,4096);
[ze,pe,ke] = ellip(n,3,30,2*pi*f,'s');
[be,ae] = zp2tf(ze,pe,ke);
[he,we] = freqs(be,ae,4096);

plot(wb/(2e9*pi),mag2db(abs(hb)))
hold on
plot(w1/(2e9*pi),mag2db(abs(h1)))

plot(we/(2e9*pi),mag2db(abs(he)))
axis([0 4 -40 5])
grid
xlabel('Frequency (GHz)')
ylabel('Attenuation (dB)')
legend('Butterworth','Chebyshev','Elliptic')


[zb,pb,kb] = besself(n,2*pi*f,'low');
[bb,ab] = zp2tf(zb,pb,kb);
[hb1,wb1] = freqs(bb,ab,4096);

hold on
plot(wb1/(2e9*pi),mag2db(abs(hb1)))
dataOut1=[wb/(2e9*pi) mag2db(abs(hb))];

save('filter1.dat','dataOut1', '-ascii')
dataOut2=[w1/(2e9*pi) mag2db(abs(h1))];
save('filter2.dat','dataOut2', '-ascii')
dataOut3=[we/(2e9*pi) mag2db(abs(he))];

save('filter3.dat','dataOut3', '-ascii')
dataOut4=[wb1/(2e9*pi) mag2db(abs(hb1))];

save('filter4.dat','dataOut4', '-ascii')
```

Then I use this code in Latex to read the data and plot, but I'm getting an error regarding memory limit, how can I go about that to solve the problem. I also want to know if there is a way that I can save the data in folder and then give the path to Latex to read it.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\pgfplotstableread{filter1.dat}\datatable
\addplot table {\datatable};
\addplot table[y index=1] {\datatable};
\pgfplotstableread{filter2.dat}\datatable
\addplot table {\datatable};
\addplot table[y index=1] {\datatable};
\pgfplotstableread{filter3.dat}\datatable
\addplot table {\datatable};
\addplot table[y index=1] {\datatable};
\pgfplotstableread{filter4.dat}\datatable
\addplot table {\datatable};
\addplot table[y index=1] {\datatable};

\legend{$\nu=0$, $\nu=1$, $\nu=2$, $\nu=3$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hello, have you tried using MATLAB file called matlab2tikz? Sometimes, you will receive this error when you are using so many data points to create a graph that you would only need fewer points.

Comment: I tried everything but this method is the best since I can add comments to the figure  directly in Latex

Comment: try using lualatex instead of pdflatex  it will use dynamic memory allocation

Comment: @Diana you can also add comments to the matlab2tikz generated graphs, using conventional tikz nodes, something like `/node {} at (1,7) {this is a node}`. I probably did not get the syntax correctly, as it's been a couple of months since I used latex, but that should be it. Also, matlab2tikz's `cleanfig` function is really a life-saver in these 'out of memory' situations